# Why does WPF's DataGrid behave differently when re-initialized with identical code?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a `UserControl` with the following Xaml representing a simple `DataGrid` with buttons for testing:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid x:Name="TestGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1"  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button  Content="Init View" Click="InitViewButton_Click"/>
        <Button  Content="Add" Click="AddButton_Click"/>
        <Button  Content="Change Ids" Click="ChangeIdButton_Click"/>
        <Button  Content="Filter X" Click="FilterButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And (in code-behind) following code:

```
public ListCollectionView TestView {get; set;}

public ObservableCollection<TestItem> TestItems {get; set;} 

private void init()
{
    var result = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>()
    {
        new TestItem() { Id = 1, Name = "First A" },
        new TestItem() { Id = 2, Name = "Second A" },
        new TestItem() { Id = 3, Name = "Third A" },

    };

    TestItems = result;

    var view = new ListCollectionView(TestItems);
    view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(TestItem.Id), ListSortDirection.Descending));
    view.IsLiveSorting = true;
    view.Filter = o => (o as TestItem)?.Name.Contains("A") ?? false;
    TestView = view;
}

private void InitViewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    init();
    TestGrid.ItemsSource = TestView;
    TestGrid.Items.Refresh();
}

private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = new TestItem() { Id = 99, Name = "New AX" };

    TestItems.Add(item);
}

private void ChangeIdButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var testItem in TestItems)
    {
        testItem.Id = Random.Shared.Next(1000);
    }
}

private void FilterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TestView.Filter = o => (o as TestItem)?.Name.Contains("X") ?? false;
}
```

After clicking on "Init View" the `DataGrid` is populated as expected and the other buttons work as expected, e.g. when changing the Ids the rows are resorted.

If I then click on "Init View" again, everything is ok, except for re-sorting, i.e. changing the Ids does not resort the rows - the displayed items are updated correctly, though.

How can this be?

Side note: despite not having set `IsLiveFiltering`, filtering works as expected, e.g. if I remove the "A" from a Name the item is removed from the `DataGrid`.

Comment: When you refer to "Init Items", are you intending to refer to "Init View"?

Comment: Not where I can test this right now, but, I suspect that the problem revolves around setting ItemsSource dynamically in the InitViewButton_Click method. Have you tried simply databinding that property in the xaml? I have a foggy memory of struggling in a similar fashion with DG sort. It had to do with assigning the datasource after setting the SortDescriptions, but I don't remember the specific details.

Comment: I should also ask, how is your control being initialized upon creation. Are you calling init() from an event not shown in your example code? If so, look at the difference between what you are doing there and in the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like somehow the `SortDescriptions` are being cleared after setting the `DataGrid ItemsSource` to the new `ListCollectionView` (after the first time).

If you add the `SortDescription` after `TestGrid.ItemsSource = TestView`, it works:

```
private void init()
{
    var result = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>()
    {
        new TestItem() { Id = 1, Name = "First A" },
        new TestItem() { Id = 2, Name = "Second A" },
        new TestItem() { Id = 3, Name = "Third A" },
    };

    TestItems = result;

    var view = new ListCollectionView(TestItems);

    view.IsLiveSorting = true;
    view.Filter = o => (o as TestItem)?.Name.Contains("A") ?? false;
    TestView = view;
}

private void InitViewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    init();
    TestGrid.ItemsSource = TestView;
    TestView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(TestItem.Id), ListSortDirection.Descending));
    //TestGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```